# Using a dictionary to populate a UITableView data in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary, tableview

I am currently trying to populate a UITableView with data from a dictionary. I am getting an error "Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary'". I know what it means but I don't know how to fix it. I know how to make it work with an array. Is it possible to use a dictionary?

```
// my dictionary 

var contactDictionary: Dictionary = [String: String]()

//function that throws error

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactcell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
  let object = contactDictionary[indexPath.row]

}
```

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered and accessed by a key, not an integer index.  I would suggest that you extract the keys into an array and use that to access the relevant object out of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use contactDictionary.keys to retrieve the array of keys and use the key to find value, but the order may change every time; Swift does not guarantee the order of dictionary. If order is important, you can search for 3rd party OrderedDictionary or other data structures.

Comment: Okay I think I understand. Order is not important in this is situation so that should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your dictionary declaration code from

```
var contactDictionary: Dictionary = [String: String]()
```

to

```
var contactDictionary = [String: String]()
```

or

```
var contactDictionary: [String: String] = [:]
```

As already mentioned in comments Dictionary is an unordered collection. If you need to keep it sorted you can use an array of key value pairs:

```
var contacts: [(key: String, value: String)] = []
```